# Create multiple charts using matplotlib from json in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, matplotlib, charts

this is my first post on stackoverflow, so sorry if I do something wrong.

I am creating a flask web app where you can answer surveys.

from the survey responses I would like to create charts in which to show the survey responses based on user information, for example to show how many people like pizza in relation to their age.

I save the survey results in a json format like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "question": {
        "Do you like pasta?": "no", 
        "Do you like pizza": "no"
      }, 
      "user_info": {
        "age": 17, 
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "question": {
        "Do you like pasta?": "no", 
        "Do you like pizza": "yes"
      }, 
      "user_info": {
        "age": 19, 
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "question": {
        "Do you like pasta?": "yes", 
        "Do you like pizza": "no"
      }, 
      "user_info": {
        "age": 13, 
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

il chart che vorrei creare è questo:

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLNrE.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


labels = ['13', '14', '15', '16']
respose_1 = [50, 20, 15, 66]
respose_2 = [79, 88, 71, 50]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, respose_1, width, label='Si')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, respose_2, width, label='No')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Respose')
ax.set_xlabel('Age')
ax.set_title('TEST.')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()


def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test3.png')
plt.show()
```

so I need the labels, respose_1, respose_2.
i spent hours trying to extract this information from the json but i couldn't.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your json file and extract the data fairly easily. Here is a method that tries to be relatively agnostic to the content, but I'm sure there are better ways:

```
import json
d = '''
{
  "results": [
    {
      "question": {
        "Do you like pasta?": "no", 
        "Do you like pizza": "no"
      }, 
      "user_info": {
        "age": 17, 
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "question": {
        "Do you like pasta?": "no", 
        "Do you like pizza": "yes"
      }, 
      "user_info": {
        "age": 19, 
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "question": {
        "Do you like pasta?": "yes", 
        "Do you like pizza": "no"
      }, 
      "user_info": {
        "age": 13, 
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    }
  ]
}
'''

j = json.loads(d)
df = pd.DataFrame()
for a in j['results']:
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(a).ffill(axis=1).drop(columns='question').T])
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

> ```
>   Do you like pasta? Do you like pizza age gender
> 0                 no                no  17   Male
> 1                 no               yes  19   Male
> 2                yes                no  13   Male
> ```

The you can easily plot with `seaborn`:

```
sns.countplot(data=df, x='age', hue='Do you like pasta?')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

List of all yes or no sayings by age in json data

```
d = {
  "results": [
    {
      "question": {
        "Do you like pasta?": "no", 
        "Do you like pizza": "no"
      }, 
      "user_info": {
        "age": 17, 
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "question": {
        "Do you like pasta?": "no", 
        "Do you like pizza": "yes"
      }, 
      "user_info": {
        "age": 19, 
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "question": {
        "Do you like pasta?": "yes", 
        "Do you like pizza": "no"
      }, 
      "user_info": {
        "age": 13, 
        "gender": "Male"
      }
    }
  ]
}
label=set()
for i in d["results"]:
  label.add(i["user_info"]["age"])
labels=sorted(label)
print("Ages")
print(labels)
#[13,17,19]
said_yes_pasta=[]
said_no_pasta=[]
said_yes_pizza=[]
said_no_pizza=[]
for i in labels:
  _said_yes_pasta=0
  _said_no_pasta=0
  _said_yes_pizza=0
  _said_no_pizza=0
  for j in d["results"]:
    if(j["user_info"]["age"]==i):
      response_pasta=j["question"]["Do you like pasta?"]
      if(response_pasta=="yes"):
        _said_yes_pasta+=1
      else:
        _said_no_pasta+=1
      response_pizza=j["question"]["Do you like pizza"]
      if(response_pizza=="yes"):
        _said_yes_pizza+=1
      else:
        _said_no_pizza+=1
  said_yes_pasta.append(_said_yes_pasta)
  said_yes_pizza.append(_said_yes_pizza)

  said_no_pasta.append(_said_no_pasta)
  said_no_pizza.append(_said_no_pizza)
print("number of dont cake lovers")
print(said_no_pasta)
#[0, 1, 1]
print("number of dont cake pizza")
print(said_no_pizza)
#[1,1,0]
print("number of cake lovers")
print(said_yes_pasta)
#[1,0,0]
print("number of pizza lovers")
print(said_yes_pizza)
#[0,0,1]
```

for example
Take the list of **said_yes_pizza**

output

```
[0,0,1]
```

age list

```
[13,17,19]
```

> 13 year old 0 person said yes to the question I love pizza
>
> 19 year old 1 person said yes to this question